# How to use awk to match only the given string and not anything else

Tags: linux, awk

I have this file containing these contents

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

I need to `awk` only the `ID="centos"` part. I tried:

```
awk /ID=/{print} file.txt
```

But this gives the output both `ID="centos"` and `VERSION_ID="7"`

How to only `awk` the string given in the pattern?

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following(`grep` could be also used since question is about `awk` so going with it).

```
awk '/^ID="/' Input_file
```

- Use an anchor `^` to check if line starts from `ID=`.
- Then add `ID="` to make sure it only Matches `ID=` string NOT anything else.
- Why string `VERSION_ID=` will not be matched because it is NOT starting from `ID` it contains ID, which is why we used `^` in our condition check.
- `awk` works on method of `pattern`/`condition` then `action` so no action is mentioned here, that's why default action printing of current line will happen.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `awk` if you like, but the normal tool for the job is simply `grep` with the REGEX anchored at the beginning of the line, e.g.

```
$ grep '^ID=' /etc/os-release
ID="centos"
```

(that doesn't mean there is anything wrong with using `awk`, but generally here you would think `grep`. I presume the file you are parsing is `/etc/os-release`)

Answer (score 2):

Use this for exact matching:

```
$ awk -F= '$1=="ID"' file
```

Output:

```
ID="centos"
```

If you need the field separator to be something else, use:

```
$ awk 'split($0,a,/=/)&&a[1]=="ID"' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `awk` code with `^` goes perfectly:

```
awk /^ID=/{print} file
ID="centos"
```